# Replacement for Pinnacle Studio Importer

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, video-editing, pinnacle-studio

I asked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/184198/pinnacle-studio-14-importer-crashes-on-win7-x64) tips how to fix Pinnacle Studio 14 Importer which crashes on 64-bit Win7. So far, nothing really helpful has come up. Now, I realized that importing from HDV camcorder could very likely be done with *some other software* and editing could be done on PS as usual.

Output video file is probably standard MPEG-2/HDV-1080i50, audio is separated to two WAV files, one for each channel.

**What SW can import video files from HDV camcorder in a format compatible with PS?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [HDVsplit](http://strony.aster.pl/paviko/hdvsplit.htm) to be adequate. Hope this helps others too.